# Logstash 6.2.4 - match time does not default to current date

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am using logstash 6.2.4 with the following config:

```
input {
  stdin { }
}


filter {
  date {
    match => [ "message","HH:mm:ss" ]
  }
}

output {
  stdout { }
}
```

With the following input:

```
10:15:20
```

I get this output:

```
{
       "message" => "10:15:20",
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "DESKTOP-65E12L2",
    "@timestamp" => 2019-01-01T09:15:20.000Z
}
```

I have just a time information, but would like to parse it as current date.
Note that current date is 1. March 2019, so I guess that `2019-01-01` is some sort of default ?

How can I parse time information and add current date information to it ?

I am not really interested in any `replace` or other blocks as according to the documentation, parsing the time should default to current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a new field merging the current date with the field that contains your time information, which in your example is the `message` field, then your `date` filter will need to be tested against this new field, you can do this using the following configuration.

```
filter {
    mutate {
       add_field => { "current_date" => "%{+YYYY-MM-dd} %{message}" }
    }
    date {
        match => ["current_date", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
}
```

The result will be something like this:

```
{
    "current_date" => "2019-03-03 10:15:20",
      "@timestamp" => 2019-03-03T13:15:20.000Z,
            "host" => "elk",
         "message" => "10:15:20",
        "@version" => "1"
}
```

Comment: I thought as much. Thanks for the clarification.